# How to get feature names while using HashingVectorizer in python?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I want to make a 2D binary array (n_samples, n_features), where each sample is a text string and each feature is a word(unigram).

The problem is number of sample is 350000 and nunmber of feature is 40000 but my RAM size is 4GB only.

1. I am getting memory error after using CountVectorizer. So, is there any other way(like mini-batch) to do this?
2. If I use HashingVectorizer then how to get the feature_names? i.e. which column correspond to which feature?, because get_feature_names() method is not available in HashingVectorizer.

Comment: The purpose of the [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) is to get a reasonable vector representation of text *without* storing the feature names.

Answer (score 4):

To get feature names for HashingVectorizer you can take a random sample of documents, compute hashes for them and learn which hash correspond to which tokens this way. It is not perfect because there can be other tokens which correspond to a given column, and there can be collisions, but often this is enough to inspect the vectorization result (or e.g. coefficients of a linear classifier which uses hashing features).

A shameless plug - https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5 package has this implemented:

```
from eli5.sklearn import InvertableHashingVectorizer

# vec should be a HashingVectorizer instance
ivec = InvertableHashingVectorizer(vec) 
ivec.fit(docs_sample)  # e.g. each 10-th or 100-th document
names = ivec.get_feature_names()
```

See also: [Debugging Hashing Vectorizer](http://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn-text.html#debugging-hashingvectorizer) section in eli5 docs.

Answer (score 3):

1. Mini batches are not supporting in countvectorizer. However, hashing vectorizer of sklearn has `partial_fit()` that you can use.
2. Quoting sklearn documentation "There is no way to compute the inverse transform (from feature indices to string feature names) which can be a problem when trying to introspect which features are most important to a model."